# In acumatica, is there a reason why some published customisation projects disappear from the Publish Customisation screen?

Tags: acumatica, publish

I have found recently that a couple of newly created customisation projects seem to have disappeared from the Publish Customisation screen. I was wanting to make a change to one of them but I couldn't find the project anywhere.

On the login screen, I can see which customisations are published, including the two projects that have disappeared, which I have highlighted. The changes in those projects are still working, which is great, but if something was to go wrong or I needed to change the functionality, then I wouldn't be able to find it.

Here is the login screen with the publish projects highlighted.

[image: Login screen with customisations]

And here is the publish customisation screen which is sorted by all published customisations. As you can see, the two highlighted projects are missing.

[image: Publish Customisation screen]

Do you know if there is a reason why they would be hidden, and if there is a way to make them appear in this screen again?

Thanks for any assistance on this.

Comment: Does the instance have multiple tenants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joshua mentioned, the instance has multiple tenants, so I just needed to make sure that I published my customisation to all tenants.

Comment: No that is not needed, pick one tenant and use it as the main one, if you need a SQL release item aka dashboards use the publish to multiple tenants function

Comment: Thanks for that @JvD, I'll make sure to set that up